# Django: Tuple/Fixed size list of model fields

Tags: django, models, django-1.7

I am looking for a elegant way to store a tuple/list in a django model.

My Model looks like this at the moment:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):

    val_0 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_1 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_2 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_3 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_4 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_5 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_6 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_7 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_8 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    val_9 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Is there a more convienent way to create a fixed size list of model-fields?

Would be nice to access the values of the fields via my_obj.val[3]

Comment: Why not use a relation?

Comment: @Serafeim can you elaborate?

Comment: I just mean to create a Value model with a foreign key to your MyClass model and a val SmallIntegerField!

Comment: Then I still have to address every value individually   and can't iterate. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You definitely can iterate! If obj is an instance of MyClass you can use obj.value_set.all() to get a queryset (iterable) with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PickledField:
**Setup**

```
pip install django-picklefield
```

**Model**

```
from picklefield.fields import PickledObjectField
class MyClass(models.Model):
    val = PickledObjectField(default=(0,)*10)
```

**Usage**

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.val[0] = 1
obj.val[5] = 4
obj.save()
val = obj.val[0]
```